# SBS 2008 - GPO not being applied on Vista clients

Tags: windows-vista, group-policy, windows-sbs-2008

I'm having some terrible trouble with some GPO's. There are only three items we need:

1. Map a network drive
2. Copy an item to the local drive
3. Create a desktop shortcut

I've created these GPO's and linked it in the OU 'SBSUsers'. On XP machines, this will apply no problems.

On Vista machines, however, despite `GPRESULT /R` telling me the items are applied; they're really not. There are no Events in the client logs I can see to tell me of an issue either, and the result wizard from the GPMC also indicates the objects are being applied.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Group Policy *Preferences* then you need to make sure you have the [client side extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab60dc87-884c-46d5-82cd-f3c299dac7cc&displaylang=en) installed on the Vista machines.

Comment: Thanks. After further testing this in combination with a drive letter assignation error was the cause.